# Construct an adjacency matrix

Tags: r, adjacency-matrix

We want to construct an adjacency matrix (value of 1 if `A_Number` called `B_Number`, 0 if otherwise). 
`Weight`= number of times the two numbers called.

Input:

```
B = matrix(c(1,4,1, 2,4,1, 3,2,1, 4,5,1, 5,2,1),
           nrow = 5,
           ncol = 3,
           byrow = TRUE)

colnames(B) <- c("A_NUMBER", "B_NUMBER", "Weight")

#      A_NUMBER B_NUMBER Weight
# [1,]        1        4      1
# [2,]        2        4      1
# [3,]        3        2      1
# [4,]        4        5      1
# [5,]        5        2      1
```

Wanted output:

[image]

We tried following code:

```
p<-as.matrix(dcast(SNA_data, A_NUMBER~B_NUMBER, value.var="W", fill=0))
```

But this did not gave as an adjacency matrix as the names of the rows were not the same as the names of the columns. 
Does somebody know how to make a proper adjacency matrix?

Comment: `m <- matrix(0L, nrow(B), nrow(B)); m[B[, 1:2]] <- B[, 3L]; m` I'm sure there's a more clever way, can't think of it right now

Comment: you could let `igraph` do the work for you... `as_adjacency_matrix(graph_from_data_frame(B), attr="Weight", sparse=FALSE)`

Comment: ot to use `dcast` set your columns to factors : `B_df <- as.data.frame(B) ; 
B_df[ c("A_NUMBER", "B_NUMBER")] <- lapply(B_df[ c("A_NUMBER", "B_NUMBER")],factor, levels=unique(c(B[, c("A_NUMBER", "B_NUMBER")])))  ; dcast(B_df, A_NUMBER~B_NUMBER, value.var="Weight", fill=0, drop=FALSE) `

Answer (score 1):

`xtabs(Weight ~ A_NUMBER + B_NUMBER,B)` will do it.  If you want the zero rows/columns as well, just add some dummy rows (Weight=0) to your matrix, covering the full range of values that A_NUMBER and B_NUMBER might take.

Comment: Our original dataset consists of a few million entries so adding some dummy variables for the zero rows to cover all ranges would be hard? But we need to have a square matrix otherwise our code won't make a social network graph from the adjacency matrix.

Comment: If you want any zero rows/columns included then the `igraph` solution in the comments above is probably the easiest.

Comment: Actually, you could use `xtabs` after setting the A_ and B_ to factor re comment above. So use `xtabs(Weight ~ A_NUMBER + B_NUMBER, B_df, sparse=TRUE)` , which is probably preferable to dcast as it can return a sparse matrix (which i assume you want if you have a few million obs)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It's a good solution but it still doesn't result in a square matrix because in our actual dataset, some numbers appear twice in the A_number column. We think the only solution is that all A and B numbers appear in both the columns and rows so if all numbers are unique, a matrix of 5x5 would result in an adjacency matrix of 10x10

Comment: @CharlotteDeVlieghere ; you should update your question to show why this doesnt work. For example, `d = data.frame(A_NUMBER = c(1,1:5), B_NUMBER = c(5, 6:10), Weight = 1:6)` had non-unique nodes in coloumn 1 and different nodes in A and B_. We can set these to factor `d[ c("A_NUMBER", "B_NUMBER")] <- lapply(d[ c("A_NUMBER", "B_NUMBER")], factor, levels=unique(unlist(d[, c("A_NUMBER", "B_NUMBER")])))` and then the `xabs` solution should work `xtabs(Weight ~ A_NUMBER + B_NUMBER, d, sparse=TRUE)` (10x10 matrix) .

Comment: The `igraph` soln also seems to work `as_adjacency_matrix(graph_from_data_frame(d), attr="Weight", sparse=TRUE)`

Comment: This solution works perfectly, thank you very much for all your help @user20650